# process apparently never started in /home/jenkins/workspace/developer-console@tmp/durable-28a71889

Tags: docker, jenkins, npm, jenkins-blueocean

All aver the internet I didn't find a solution.
I'm learning this tutorial about how to build a node.js and React app with Jenkins : https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-node-js-and-react-app-with-npm/#fork-sample-repository

During the build, I got the error

> process apparently never started in
>   /home/jenkins/workspace/developer-console@tmp/durable-28a71889
>
> (running Jenkins temporarily with
>   -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true
>   might make the problem clearer)
>
> script returned exit code -2

My Jenkinsfile looks like :

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node:6-alpine' 
            args '-p 3000:3000' 
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                sh 'npm install' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please do you know how could I correct it? During the process, when I check, the `node:6-alpine` container is created and running without errors.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @DrorWeiss make sure that the name of the pipeline.yml doesn't have a space a the end of the file name

Comment: Did you found the solution for this?

Comment: @deepanshu, i finally changed for gitlab-ci it is more easy to use.

Comment: @TeddyKossoko Thanks, I reinstalled everything and its working now.